# scaling in discretized PDE system

Tags: matlab, elliptic-pde, optimal-control

I want to solve the following system via Matlab 
$\Omega=(0,1)^2$

$$\Delta y=\frac{1}{\alpha} p$$
$$ -\Delta p= y -1 $$
$$p|_{\partial \Omega}=0,~y|_{\partial \Omega}=0$$

using

```
    n=50;
    alpha=1;
    A=gallery('poisson',n);

    K=[A -1/alpha*speye(n^2);
       speye(n^2) A];
    b=[zeros(n^2,1) -ones(n^2,1)];
    solution=K\b;
    %embedding with boundaries...
```

To my surprise this leads to (I think) a correct answer, however I usually have this scaling factor $\frac{1}{h^2}=(n+1)^2$ in it. Taking $-\Delta y =1$ with zero boundaries as an example, this leads to $$\frac{1}{h^2}Ay=1_{n\times1}$$

Is my code incorrect, or does this factor vanish somehow?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Are you *sure* the answer is right? I'd start with a manufactured solution (i.e., instead of $1$, pick a "nice" optimal state $y$ that satisfies the boundary conditions -- e.g., a product of sines and cosines -- compute (analytically!) the Laplacian to get the optimal adjoint state $p$, and then compute (analytically) the Laplacian and subtract $y$ to get the target $y_d$ (in place of $1$ here)); then you can see if the magnitude is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I actually did this with $f(x,y)=sin(\pi x)sin(\pi y)$, and $y_d=f(x,y)(1-4 \alpha \pi^4 $ with the result $\|f-solution_h \|_\infty \le 10^{-5}$. For the proposed problem above, the outcome looks  at least reasonable (correct is a bit strong).

Comment: And does the error go to zero with the expected rate as $h\to 0$? Does it change when you change $\alpha$ (a lot)?

Comment: choosing $\alpha=10^{-i}, i=2,3.4...150$ the error does get lower with increasing $i$, however for increasing $n$ it kind of stucks at this value.

Comment: Then there is indeed a problem. What happens if you try with the correct scaling?

Comment: what is the correct scaling? If I go with $\frac{1}{h^2}A$ instead of $A$ I get a similiar result.

Comment: That would be the correct scaling for a finite difference stencil. How do you treat the boundary conditions? (Be careful with supremum-type estimates, they could trip over boundary layer effects if the conditions aren't imposed correctly.)

Comment: since the boundary conditions are zero. I can just u=zeros(n+2,n+2);u(2:n,2:n)=reshape(solution(1:n^2),n,n). When I use gallery('poisson',n) isn't that exactly for finite differnces on a uniform quadratic grid?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to consider that you're only working with the interior node when constructing your solution.

Comment: ...in case we don't have zero boundaries? So is there any mistake left which I dont recognize?

Comment: I meant for, e.g., $sin(\pi x)$ that $x$ goes from $1/n$ to $(n-1)/n$ instead of $0$ and $1$ and especially for the construction of $y_d$. The point is that your code (and your answer) is not correct -- otherwise $y/h^2$ and $p/h^2$ should also be a solution to your system, which can be verified by inserting is not the case -- but the effect may be small for the choice of parameters you are looking at.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Going back to the initial problem. When I solve $\frac{1}{h^2}Ay-\alpha^{-1}Idp=0,~\frac{1}{h^2}Ap+Idy=-1$ as a linear system is not correct?